# NodeJS Express Socket IO Routes & MVC

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, routes

When working in HTTP protocol routing is quite easy.
You're looking at the header, get the route, and then have a dictionary that defines which routes goes to which controller.

For example:

```
{
    "/"        : { "controller" : "MainController", "action" : "index", "di" : {} },
    "/Login"    : { "controller" : "LoginController", "action" : "login", "di" :  {"LoginService"} }
}
```

I would like to try and match that behaviour when working with socket io on nodejs express.

The problem is, I don't know how to "listen" to any **on** and look at its properties as if it was an http request and I'm to check its headers.

So the big question is:
**How can I listen to ANY event?**

Let's assume the following desired code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.any(Route, callback);
}
```

Where **any** is a made up function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io supports a similar [middleware framework](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn) like express, if you want to intercept *every* request then you can do:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
   // inspect socket.handshake.headers
});
```